# Ruby On Rails Routing On Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, rails-routing

I have the Rails Environment setup on my Mac.

**Local**: `~/GitHub/Warehouse/`

**Server**: `http://localhost:3001/`

Here is my **/config/routes.rb**:

```
Warehouse::Application.routes.draw do

    resources :events
    resources :locations
    resources :categories
    resources :items

    get "home/index"
    root :to => "home#index"

end
```

I put my application on the server in a folder `~/warehouse`. It has a symbolic link of `~/public_html/warehouse/` that points to `~/warehouse/public`.

**So my url is:** 
http://showtime.www77.a2hosting.com/warehouse

I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/warehouse" for 184.175.153.98 at Sat Nov 24 21:47:24 -0500 2012

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/warehouse"):
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `send'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
    passenger (3.0.15) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
    passenger (3.0.15) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

What should my routes.rb table be like?? I'm confused with this.  Please let me know what I should do to make this work.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Rails apps usually like to be at the root of the domain. If you decide against that, things get more complicated.

Comment: suggesting that i do a subdomain, instead?  something like warehouse.domain.com/

Comment: That would make your life much easier, yes.

Comment: @AlexWayne, thanks for the tip!  Does anyone else have any answers of how I could accomplish this? If that was the route I decide to go?

Comment: Iam confused on what you are doing. which app server are you running? what is your apache/nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `config.ru`

```
map "/warehouse" do
  run Warehouse::Application
end
```

This mounts your application and rack middleware to the specified path or URI and all the children paths under it, so your routes should work properly. If you have problems with your assets then, adjust `config.action_controller.asset_host` within your environment configuration files in config/environments.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a namespace. You still need to

```
namepace :warehouse do
  resources ....
end
```

root_to 'warehouse#pages#home'